# How to add APP intents or intents using Siri Kit?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, appintents

I want to open the app on saying "Hey siri, Send Money"?

I have a money transfer app. I want to add Siri support. Such as upon saying "Hey siri, Send Money", it should open the app (if not running) and go to a specific screen.

I have tried adding the app intents extension and the following code.

```
import AppIntents

struct SendMoney: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "SendMoney"
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return .result()
    }
}

struct MyAppShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider{
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut]{
        AppShortcut(intent: SendMoney(), phrases: ["Transfer Money in DemoApp"])
    }
}
```

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I added the code for reference

Comment: It appears that you will be getting compilation errors. You should add that detail to your question.